# Do unused functions in a React Hook cause application bundle size issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a library utils, which contains about 20 functions, in my application and I want to create a hook to wrap it. My question is: if I do that, do the unused functions will increase my application bundle size?

**Example**

I'd use `useUtils` this way:

```
// Component A
const { formatDate } = useUtils();

// Component B
const { roundNumber } = useUtils();

// Component C
const { formatDate, transformData } = useUtils();
```

Each component destructures only the functions that it'll use, but the others will also be loaded at the time I call `useUtils()`.

May this scenario increase the application bundle size at build?

Note: all my utils functions are pure.

Comment: Are you using webpack? https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ this can be useful.

Comment: @Peter done. I've made some considerations about my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not adversely affect your bundle size (if they did, it would be a trivial amount).  A bigger concern would be excess libraries being used, un-minified code, un-optimized images, etc...